# Input box that automatically create and name a folder

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble creating a macro that automates in creating specified folders.

I'd like to create an excel file with a button. in which when you click the button,
a pop up question will appear and ask for a date("input date").

Then it will create a folder at the directory in the cell B11.
The name of the folder is sale + ("input date")
Your help is highly appreciated. thank you :)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code-writing service... While many people will gladly *assist* you with specific problems, simply giving us a list of requirements and expecting others to do the work, is frowned upon.

Comment: Consider using `Dir` and `MkDir` functions, or alternatively the `FileSystemObject`.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a sample:

```
Sub FolderMaker()
    Dim s As String
    s = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Please enter date in format yyyymmdd", Type:=2)
    s = Range("B11") & s
    MsgBox s

    On Error Resume Next
        MkDir s
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

with **B11** like:

[image]

To customize you would use `s = Range("B11") & "sale" & s`